# XML Parse error from suds call

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing, suds

I'm getting an error when running a suds call (I'm using suds-jurko). I've tested this out on a different export and it worked fine. Just for whatever reason the data I'm trying to pull has some issues with and I'm trying to figure out what the exact issue is. I've pulled the data using another method, but there is no column 209, so trying to understand better what is causing that to think that.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 207, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: reference to invalid character number: line 96835, column 209
```

Any thoughts of how to debug this are most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line 96835 sounds like you're either parsing an extremely large XML file, or you're trying to parse something that isn't XML -- maybe you have a blob in there that you didn't properly encode and that contains XML tags?

Comment: It's an email subscriber list that I'm pulling from the service my company uses. I've only found one function to export subscribers and it should return a csv.

Comment: A CSV is not XML-safe.

Comment: You will need to properly encode the content of that CSV

Comment: The call only allows one argument, the call literally is just `export_csv = api.service.runExportAndReturnDataAsText(4)`

Comment: this looks like what you'd do on the receiving end, if I understand correctly-- My point is that the program that puts together the XML isn't producing correct XML.